# Simple proof of oscillation/nodal theorem in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

In L. D. Landau and E. M. Lifshitz Quantum Mechanics it is [said](http://books.google.ru/books?id=J9ui6KwC4mMC&pg=PA60&lpg=PA60&dq=oscillation%20theorem%20quantum%20mechanics&source=bl&ots=-wQuYhIunf&sig=ezGcT-Q1G1gbv9pL-ZtGO_tUJJ4&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdpJ3_3bzRAhVFYJoKHc4TAbUQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=oscillation%20theorem%20quantum%20mechanics&f=false) about oscillation theorem, is there any short and simple way to prove it, which would be understandable for the 2nd year student of math/physics department?

[image]

As one can see it states that in bounded (let it be one dimensional) space $\psi$ function of the ground energy state have zero "zeroes" and in $n$th excited state have exactly $n$ "zeroes". How one can prove it in short and easy way?

**Note:** this is not a hometasklike question. This is a try to deeper understand the general physics course.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186140/50583, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75205/50583 Also, please *type out* quotes instead of adding a picture of text - the pictures are not searchable for the text they contain, hence less useful than actual text.

Comment: I sketched a proof of the nodal theorem in my Phys.SE answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/295996/2451).

Comment: Thx, @Qmechanic, it is very helpful.

Comment: Also look up "Sturm-Liouville problem".

Comment: There is a nice proof of a weaker result in the textbook by Albert Messiah.  He shows that, if $E_2> E_1$, then $\psi_2$ must have more zeroes than $\psi_1$.  The stronger result depends on technical properties of solutions to Sturm-Liouville systems.